# Using Alphablend, transparent Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, alphablending

I was using alphblend transparent textbox for a project but I ended up with a problem.
when I use the 0 value then it did not make the transparent background. 0 Value turns the background into a gray color.

[Picture of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwfgH.png)

while I want this kind of effect.

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToR2E.png)

Here is the code which I am using.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2 = new ZBobb.AlphaBlendTextBox();

    // alphaBlendTextBox2
    // 
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.BackAlpha = 0;
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Comic Sans MS", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(94, 98);
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.Multiline = true;
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.Name = "alphaBlendTextBox2";
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 160);
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.TabIndex = 0;
    this.alphaBlendTextBox2.Text = "Bob Bradley";
    // 
    this.Controls.Add(this.alphaBlendTextBox2);

}
```

I am using 4.5 .NET Framework.

Please guide me where I am making any mistake.

Comment: I don't know this specific user control. But it could be that it uses 0 as a magic number for showing exactly this behavior (by design so to say). You could try changing the alpha value in the assigned color as well (i.e in FromArgb(0,R,G,B)) and see if that does the trick. You could also consider if BackAlpha = 1 is sufficiently transparent for your application.

Comment: the author of the code is using 0 value.

Comment: hi thanks for you help. actually i am getting another error. which is "Control does not support transparent background colors" I've tried " this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);"In designer,on forms load, literally everywhere. But the error is there how can i remove this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I Got the Problem.
The main problem was of parent. Parent of text box was set to form. I have to change it to the picture box. Simple
like.

```
textbox.parent=picturebox1;
```